# Почему другие пользователи не видят мой github?

Tags: github

Я не могу разобраться с проблемой или хотя бы понять причину. У меня есть публичный аккаунт github https://github.com/ZelElizaveta, в настройках не стоит галочка о приватности аккаунта, я вижу все мои репозитории и аккаунт, но для других пользователей он не доступен, выходит 404 ошибка страница не найдена. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой ситуацией?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой аккаунт, он живой и если я авторизована, я могу перейти по ссылке, если нет тоже получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Адрес точно правильный?

Comment: У вас самой эта ссылка разве открывается? Перейдите в свой профиль и скопируйте адрес из адресной строки браузера.

Comment: Скриншот своей страницы в студию.

Comment: Интересно, но гугл про такую страницу помнит. Может быть страница удалена?

Comment: Да точно правильный, я могу перейти по этой ссылке. И если я авторизована то мой аккаунт у меня открывается и есть доступ ко всей информации, но если я выхожу из аккаунта при переходе у меня тоже 404 ошибка появляется.

Comment: Страница точно жива. Такая история происходит со всеми моими репозиториями

Comment: Вы случайно не в каком-нибудь спорном регионе IP имеете, типа Крыма? VPN и прочее отключено?

Comment: Нет, я из Сибири

Comment: были ли изменения username?

Comment: Ваш [аккаунт виден](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zi8c.png) с Google. По поводу Github не знаю, щяс эксперементирую)

Comment: Вам случайно [не блокировали](https://chat.openai.com/share/197060aa-afc5-4c7b-a0e0-59fb219f7f9e)?

Comment: Похоже на shadowban https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19647524

Comment: В общем кажется стоит писать в техподдержку гитхаба

Comment: Спасибо всем за участие в моей проблеме, я поняла, что github меня просто заблочил, но причин этого я не знаю. Написала в тех. поддержку.

Answer (score 2):

Письмо в техподдержку помогло. Мой аккаунт снова активен.