# Никто не видит мою GitHub-страницу

Tags: github

Создал аккаунт на GitHub, опубликовал первый репозиторий.

И репозиторий, и аккаунт являются публичными, но при попытке посетить их страницы выдает 404.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: 146% вы где-то ошиблись. Ссылку-то дадите?

Comment: https://github.com/midside001

Comment: Там ничего нет. Какие ваши доказательства что этот аккаунт есть?

Comment: И да, это не ссылка на репозиторий

Comment: в правом верхнем углу есть икнока, после нажатия откроется меню где есть 'your profile', после перехода можно скапировать верхную ссылку, вот это и есть ссылка на акк.

Comment: [Почему другие пользователи не видят мой github?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1545949)

Comment: Ссылка на репозиторий https://github.com/midside001/MS_BN_1